# Linate airport (LIN, Milan, Italy): can I go the night before for an early morning flight?

Tags: italy, sleeping, lin

I have an itinerary that starts with a 6:30 AM Alitalia flight from Linate (LIN) Airport in July.  Given this early start time and that I would be checking bags for an international itinerary so I need to be there early anyway, I am attempting to determine the feasibility of going to the airport at around midnight the night before.  I have Skyteam Elite status (but not from Alitalia specifically) if that increases my options.

I simply cannot tell from internet search if Linate is a 24 hour airport.  I assume it is, but if it is not, then this is not a feasible plan.

Internet search tells me that there are several lounges in Linate (both Skyteam and cash basis), which appear to open between 5:00 and 5:30 AM.

Alitalia's website (http://www.alitalia.com/en_en/informazioni-supporto/checkin/index.html) states to check in at minimum 45 minutes in advance for midhaul international flights (this leg is to CDG) but does not state a maximum allowed check-in window or time window that the check-in counter is open.

Questions:

- When is Alitalia in Linate airport open for checking bags?
- Is Linate airport in Milan a 24 hour airport?
- What facilities are available while waiting for an airline to staff the check-in desk?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Linate *is* a 24hours airport in the sense that the building is open 24hours. The shops and facilities contained in the building however are not. This means that you can indeed spend the night landside waiting for your plane, but you can't expect to purchase food, drinks (with the exceptions of vending machines) or services. Moreover, you will probably find that sleeping in the departure side of the airport is extremely uncomfortable. Indeed [the SleepingInAirport page on Linate has various reviews on the topic](http://www.sleepinginairports.net/europe/milan_linate.htm), and most focus on the metal benches with armrest which render it impossible to lie down and sleep on them.

For completeness sake note that there are power outlets and free Wi-Fi available across the airport. Furthermore you'll most probably benefit from the company of a few homeless, which often use the airport to sleep at night. These are mostly harmless and shouldn't disturb you.

The physical check-in and baggage drop-off counters usually open a couple hours before the scheduled departure time of the aircraft. `A couple` here means anything between two to three hours. Note that this is based on personal experience with various airlines, as opposed to authoritative references.